# Array to string conversion in PHP7?

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have the next problem trying to print an array, but I get the error:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in PHP

```
for($a=0; $a<sizeof($test); $a++)
{
    $arreglo[$da]=array(
    "nombre"=>$test[$a]->Name,
    "estrellas"=>$test[$a]->Classification,
    "imagen"=>$test[$a]->Image,
    "descripcion"=>(string)$test[$a]->Description,
    "precio"=>(int)$test[$a]->TourOperations->ItemPrice,
    "broker"=>(string)$test[$a]->Broker,
    "itemcode"=>(string)$test[$a]->ItemCode,
    "token"=>(string)$test[$a]->AvailToken,
    "ContractName"=>(string)$test[$a]->TourOperations->ContractName,
    "IncomingOffice"=>(string)$test[$a]->TourOperations->IncomingOffice,

    );
    $da++;
}
```

Comment: how are you trying to `print` it ?

Comment: Add your array here

Comment: If we don't know what is in $test, we can't do much to help. At some point, something you think is a string is actually an array. PHP isn't lying to you.

Comment: Just as an aside, why not do a foreach instead of a counting for loop? `foreach($test as $object)`, and you won't have to worry about missing indexes.

Comment: did you try print_r or var_dump?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you're trying to cast an array to a string. But it's for us impossible to know where this is happening (since you're not posting the data structure of your variables) but consider this example:

```
(string)$test[$a]->TourOperations->IncomingOffice
```

If `IncomingOffice` is an array, it will cause this notice.

Answer (score 0):

This error 99% percent comes from wrong print method. Try `print_r` or `var_dump` to print your array values.

Answer (score 0):

You have to google it atleast once anyway.. there is pretty way to print array with `print_r`, best practice for printing arrays is -

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);
// for converting array to string is -
implode(" ",$array);
// implode have two parameters separator(works as glue) and array

// and for associative array you can make use of http_build_query($data, 'flags_');
echo http_build_query($array);
//which will return encoded url
```

Comment: if you find helpful you can accept as correct answer